# Big Theta Notation - simplifying

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, master-theorem

I have used the Master Theorem to solve recurrence relations. I have gotten it down to **Θ(3n<sup>2</sup>-9n)**. Does this equal **Θ(n<sup>2</sup>)**?  I have another recurrence for which the solution is **Θ(2n<sup>3</sup> - 100<sup>2</sup>)**. In BigTheta notation do you always use only the largest term? So my second one would be **Θ(n<sup>3</sup>)**? It just seems like **100n<sup>2</sup>** would be more important in the second case. So will it matter if I discard it?

Any suggestions?

Comment: "Largest term" applies if you only have one input variable; if there are several, the situation is a little different. For example, many graph algorithms have both their number of nodes and their number of edges in their complexities (for example, DFS runs in O(|V| + |E|)).

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Your assumptions are correct. The first one is **Θ(n<sup>2</sup>)** and the second one is **Θ(n<sup>3</sup>)**. When you are using **Θ** notation you only require the largest term.

In case of your second recurrence consider the `n = 1000`, then **n<sup>3</sup> = 1000000000**. Where as **100n<sup>2</sup>** is just **100000000**. As the value of n increases, n<sup>3</sup> becomes more and more predominant than 100n<sup>2</sup>.

For theoretical purpose you don't need to consider the constant, how ever large it might be. But practical applications might prefer an algorithm with a small constant even if the complexity is high. For example it might be better to use an algorithm having complexity **0.01n <sup>3</sup>** over an algorithm having **10000n<sup>2</sup>** complexity if the value of **n** is not very large.

Answer (score 0):

if we have function f(n) = 3n^2-9n , lower order terms and costants can be ignored, we consider higher order terms ,because they play major role in growth of function.
By considering only higher order term we can easily find the upper bound, here is the example.

```
                  f(n)= 3n^2-9n
  For all sufficient large value of n>=1,
                                      3n^2<=3n^2 
                           and       -9n  <= n^2

                     thus, f(n)=3n^2 -9n <= 3n^2 + n^2
                                         <= 4n^2

  *The upper bound of f(n) is 4n^2 , that means for all sufficient large 
  value of n>=1, the value of f(n) wouldn't be greater than 4n^2.* 

                  therefore,           f(n)= Θ(n^2)  where c=4 and n0=1
```

[image]

**we can directly find the upper bound by saying to ignore lower order terms and constants in the equation f(n)= 3n^2-9n , result will be the same Θ(n^2)**